# Fatal Exception Linkage Error in Android AdS gms When Migrated to Android 12 Api 31

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, admob, internals

This exception start occurring when i migrated to target SDK 31 from SDK level 30.  I am also facing other linkage error pointing towards different library code . It seem thats Google Ads is not compatible with my libraries . I tired to generate this error on my testing device but crash is not happening .

```
  Fatal Exception: java.lang.LinkageError: Method void f.h.b.b.h.a.b03.onPostExecute(java.lang.Object) overrides final method in class Lf/h/b/b/h/a/xz2; (declaration of 'f.h.b.b.h.a.b03' appears in /data/app/~~LknhSvPjgyfVuSPDP0g1mw==/org.contentarcade.apps.logomaker-zoicDfEjevaUR8k79CKfQw==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfkd.<init>(zzfkd.java:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfkd.<clinit>(zzfkd.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfkd.zzd(zzfkd.java)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfjh.zze(zzfjh.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfja.zzf(zzfja.java:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfip.zze(zzfip.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeex.zzd(zzeex.java:6)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnb.zzq(zzdnb.java:26)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdnb.zzh(zzdnb.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdmv.run(zzdmv.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfnu.zza(zzfnu.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.zzf.zza(zzf.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfnu.dispatchMessage(zzfnu.java:1)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8550)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at 
       com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

I am sharing my gradle version and other dependencies version here . If any one facing the same issue kindly give his recommendation .

**Project Gradle** [image]

**App Level Gradle Dependencies **

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def firebaseBoom = "30.4.0"
    def billingVersion = "5.0.0"
    def AdsVesion = "21.2.0"   // Upgraded to 21.2.0  due to crashes
    def work_RunTime = "2.7.1"
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation project(':bezier')
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:$AdsVesion"
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billingVersion"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
    implementation "com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1"
    //Splash Screen APi for ANdroid 12 and Above
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlin_version}"
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:76.3809.111'
    implementation 'org.chromium.net:cronet-embedded:76.3809.111'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    //this version support upto 100dps
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.caverock:androidsvg-aar:1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation project(path: ':circularrv')
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:colorpickerview:2.1.5"
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation project(path: ':eyedropper')
    implementation 'com.github.jumadeveloper:networkmanager:0.0.2'
    implementation 'com.llollox:androidtoggleswitch:2.0.1'
    //drive
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.26.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.26.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v3-rev136-1.25.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    // searchModule
    // retro fit network call api
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.7.2'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    //BOm
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:$firebaseBoom")
    // Declare the dependencies for the Crashlytics and Analytics libraries
    // When using the BoM, you don't specify versions in Firebase library dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:$work_RunTime"
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'}
```

Occurrence of this exception reduce when i came back to SDK Level 30 .

Comment: I am also getting the same problem only on release build not on debug build apk.